# Streamlit - How to let users download an Excel file from the app?

Tags: python, excel, streamlit

I want users to be able to download an Excel file by clicking a button. I have an existing Excel file, though it can also be generated from a dataframe, that I want to be provided in Excel format.

Documentation gives an example for .csv files:

```
with open('my_file.csv') as f:
    st.download_button('Download', f)
```

but I can't adapt this use case for an Excel file. I can't manage to put the excel file in the right format so that the download_button method accepts it. I tried passing pd.to_excel() object but it also didn't work.

I'll appreciate any and every suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
with open(file_path, 'rb') as my_file:
    st.download_button(label = 'Download', data = my_file, file_name = 'filename.xlsx', mime = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
```